# PHP & SQLite - Quote & Apostrophe Errors when Inserting

Tags: php, sqlite

Hi I'm having this huge issue with inserting into sqlite.

$string='Hello I'm Doing "Great" the Price is $1.00 plus [$3.00] Postage';

how I'm I going to insert that into sqlite without errors?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must ALWAYS use escaping functions or parameter binding when you use variables in sql queries, for any database. For sqlite it's [sqlite_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-escape-string.php)

```
$string='Hello I\'m Doing "Great" the Price is $1.00 plus [$3.00] Postage';
$string_to_use_in_query = sqlite_escape_string($string);
$query = "insert .... '$string_to_use_in_query'";
```

SQLite3 example:

```
$stmt = $handle->prepare('insert into table (name) values (:name)');
$stmt->bindValue(':name', $string, SQLITE3_TEXT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: but how do I write it so it doesn't give me errors when inserting, it doesn't get past the $string because its all open, how do I close it all so its ready for inserting?

Comment: your edited text shows this error Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlite_escape_string()

Comment: How do you create the connection?

Comment: function SQLite($switch,$filename,$query){
 if(!class_exists('SQLite3')) die("SQLite 3 NOT supported.");
 $handle=new SQLite3($filename, 0666);
 if($switch==1){
  $handle->query($query);
  return $handle->lastInsertRowid();
 }else{
  
  $result=$handle->query($query);
  if(!$result){
      echo $query.'<br>';
   exit;
  }
  return $result;
  #return $handle->query($query);
 }
        //$return $handle->exec($query);#didn't work on select.
}

Comment: I read that prepare fails on where querys. so instead ive used the escape string medthod, I'll edit your question to place it there, but it works perfectly.

Comment: Is it still true? The comment is 3 years old. And it only regards non-existent columns.

Comment: what the.... 3year old haha i posted this question the other day haha, you wrote on it the other day,  why it saying its 3 yrs old haha! funny stuff isnt it lol

Comment: I mean the comment at http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.prepare.php saying that it fails on where query part.